# RHEL7.7: version incompatibility between python3 and python3-devel

Tags: redhat, rhel7

First off, I'm not too familiar with the RedHat/rpm distro system, being more the Debian type in private. After an update from RHEL7.4 to RHEL7.7 on a server that I find myself administrating at work, I get this message:

```
Error: Package: python36-devel-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (@ius)
           Requires: python36-devel-3.6.8-2.el7.ius
           Removing: python36-3.6.8-2.el7.ius.x86_64 (@ius)
               python36 = 3.6.8-2.el7.ius
           Obsoleted By: python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               python36 = 3.6.8-10.el7
```

The way I read this is this: I have python36-devel-3.6.8-2 installed, and it depends on python36-3.6.8-2, which is also installed (both from IUS some time ago). However, yum would like to upgrade python36-3.6.8-2 to python3-3.6.8-10 from the current RHEL7.7 distro but it can't because that would break the dependency for python36-devel-3.6.8-2

I've done

```
$ sudo yum clean metadata
$ sudo yum install epel-release ius-release
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package epel-release-7-12.noarch already installed and latest version
Package ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
$ sudo yum update
[ ...error message like above... ]
Enable all repositories and try again? [y/N]: y
[ ...error message like above... ]
```

So my question is: How do I get my python (-devel) packages in sync?

Note: I also use Apache with mod_wsgi. Because I have all my Python3 stuff in a virtual environment, I could install Python3 from scratch and have everything squeaky clean inside that environment, including mod_wsgi. But I'm afraid that this could introduce compatibility issues between Apache and mod_wsgi. And yes, I need python3-devel because I also use C extensions.

Comment: Must you use ius repo?

Comment: No. But I'm not aware of any other "official" releases besides ius and epel.

Comment: it looks like ius is conflicting with epel. If you don't need ius, remove it

Answer (score 2):

It had nothing to do with epel or ius. This solved it:

```
$ sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```